# How to enable the Notification by default on android devices?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, notifications, android-notifications

I have recently Implemented the flutter_local_notifications and the notification is working fine. But there's one problem is that the notification doesn't show as pop up by default. The option is disabled by default in the notification settings.

My code like this :

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  ServiceContainer.initialize(Injector());

  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);

  await PreferenceHelper.create();
  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  await messaging.requestPermission(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
    provisional: false,
  );
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission();

  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );

  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      const SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent));

  runApp(const App());
  await [Permission.storage, Permission.notification].request();
}
```

Comment: here is a temporary solution idk if your problem got resolved. downgrade the "targetSdkVersion" to 32 and keep the compileSdkVersion to 33

Answer (score 1):

You need to request for notification permissions

**Requesting permissions on Android 13 or higher**

From Android 13 (API level 33) onwards, apps now have the ability to display a prompt where users can decide if they want to grant an app permission to show notifications. For further reading on this matter read https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notification-permission. To support this applications need target their application to Android 13 or higher and the compile SDK version needs to be at least 33 (Android 13). For example, to target Android 13, update your app's build.gradle file to have a targetSdkVersion of 33. Applications can then call the following code to request the permission where the requestPermission method is associated with the AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin class (i.e. the Android implementation of the plugin)

This is how you do it.

```dart
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
        FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
    AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>().requestPermission();
```

Comment: this was not work: The method 'requestPermissions' isn't defined for the type 'AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin'. (Documentation)

Comment: @NicholasJela see https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#requesting-permissions-on-android-13-or-higher